# How to Calculate Avg and how to allow only positive user input values for data in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking to find a simple beginner way to add code that If any input is negative, the program should prompt user again until  they  input  a  non‐negative  value. I also not sure how to calculate the avg only for the days that the distance is not 0.0 miles. I know that the if‐statement should check if `x` is within some value (say ±0.0001) from 0.0. Because using the statement  `if (x == 0.0)`  would  evaluate to a `false`  because the value is not stored precisely.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Lab3_1
{
  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    String[] Day = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    double[] Time = new double[7];
    double[] Distance = new double[7];
    double[] MPH = new double[7];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < Day.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Data for " + Day[i]); 

      System.out.print("Input Time in minutes");      
      Time[i] = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Input Distance in miles");
      Distance[i] = input.nextDouble();        
    } 

    for(int s = 0; s < Day.length; s++)
    {
      MPH[s] = (double)Distance[s] / ((double)Time[s] / 60);
    }

    double max = MPH[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < Day.length; i++)
    {
      if (MPH[i] > max)
      {
        max = MPH[i];
      }
    }

    double min = MPH[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < Day.length; i++)
    {
      if (MPH[i] < min)
      {
        min = MPH[i];
      }
    }

    double MPHsum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Day.length; i++)
    {      
      MPHsum = MPHsum + MPH[i];           
    }

    double avg = 0;
    avg = (double)MPHsum / Distance.length;

    System.out.println("Sum of values is " + MPHsum);
    System.out.println("Minimum pace in MPH " + min);
    System.out.println("Maximum pace in MPH " + max);
    System.out.println("Average pace in MPH " + avg);


  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem with average? I am unable to undersatand what you meant by *I also not sure how to calculate the avg only for the days that the distance is not 0.0 miles*

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Day.length; i++)
{

    System.out.println("Data for " + Day[i]); 

    System.out.print("Input Time in minutes");      
    Time[i] = input.nextDouble();

    while(Time[i] < 0){
        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again: ");
        Time[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.print("Input Distance in miles");
    Distance[i] = input.nextDouble();

    while(Distance[i] < 0){
        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again: ");
        Distance[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

}
```

Here I have created a loop which runs till `Time[i]` is less then 0, asking user to input new values again and again till a positive value is entered. Same thing for `Distance`.

Comment: I see what you have done there, and its very helpful to me. I was using a wrong statement in the while() and getting an error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the question until the response is valid then `do while` is likely more appropriate than `while`:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Input distance");
    distance[i] = input.nextDouble();
    if (distance[i] < 0.0)
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
} while (distance[i] < 0.0);
```

If you are using Java 8 then there's a far simpler way of filtering and averaging:

```
Arrays.stream(distance).filter(d -> d > 0.0).average();
```

That returns an `OptionalDouble` because you can't be sure there is an average (e.g. all the distances might be 0). You can use `ifPresent` and `getAsDouble` to use the value.

You can replace `average` with `sum`, `count`, `max` to retrieve other statistics. Or you can get all the statistics in one go:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(distance)
    .filter(d -> d > 0.0).summaryStatistics();
```

Then you can use `stats.getAverage`, `stats.getMin`, `stats.getSum` to retrieve the various statistics.

Exactly the same method can be used for getting statistics on `mph` or any other array.

Comment: I am sorry, never learned this type of code before. Can you explain how i can use Arrays.stream(distance).filter(d -> d > 0.0).average(); to add the days that do not have the distance as 0.0?

Comment: I'll add a longer explanation